# Why does Java use UTF-16 for the internal text representation

Tags: java, character-encoding

Java uses UTF-16 for the internal text representation. But why? UTF-8 as it seems to me is more flexible.

From wiki:

> UTF-8 requires either 8, 16, 24 or 32 bits (one to four octets) to
>   encode a Unicode character, UTF-16 requires either 16 or 32 bits to
>   encode a character, and UTF-32 always requires 32 bits to encode a
>   character.

Comment: Answered at [Why does Java use UTF-16 for internal string representation?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/174947/why-does-java-use-utf-16-for-internal-string-representation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java was designed and first implemented back in the days when Unicode was specified to be a set of 16 bit code-points. That is why `char` is a 16 bit type, and why `String` is modeled as a sequence of `char`.

Now, if the Java designers had been able to foresee that Unicode would add extra "code planes", they might<sup>1</sup> have opted for a 32 bit `char` type.

Java 1.0 came out in January 1996. Unicode 2.0 (which introduced the higher code planes and the surrogate mechanism) was released in July 1996.

---

Internally, I believe that some versions of Java have used UTF-8 as the representation for strings, at least at some level.  However, it is still necessary to map this to the methods specified in the `String` API because that is what Java applications require.  Doing that if the primary internal representation is UTF-8 rather than UTF-16 is going to be inefficient.

And before you suggest that they should *"just change the String APIs"* ... consider how many trillions of lines of Java code already exist that depend on the current String APIs.

---

For what it is worth, most if not all programming languages that support Unicode do it via a 16 bit `char` or `wchar` type.

---

<sup>1 - ... and possibly not, bearing in mind that memory was a lot more expensive in those days, and programmers worried much more about such things in those days.</sup>